# How to collaborate with multiple users in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, dropbox, collaboration, ludumdare

Me and few friends are going to participate in Ludum Dare in a few hours as a team. We wonder how to effectively work with Unity and VisualStudio together on multiple computers.

The first idea was to use git/svn but it turned out to be very annoying as we need to commit/push/pull way too often even for some minor changes such as some Unity button.

The second thought is to use Dropbox or some service like that. However, when .sln file is somehow changed, the project at the otherone's computer must be completely refreshed and it usually ends with import errors.

Could you give us some tips how to collaborate on the same project together as much effectively as possible?

Comment: Personally I would just deal with commiting and pushing with git. Make sure that you force text serialization for your assets, to make the commits much smaller, and have a good .gitignore for both Unity and VS

Comment: Team Foundation Server is free for up to 5 users (Visual Studio Online) as well but it is standard Source Control that requires you to do the stuff like git.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Well we finally figured it out! The solution is to use Visual Code instead of Visual Studio. Then you may use Dropbox but you mustn´t sync `Assembly-CSharp.csproj` if your team use multiple operating systems.